# How to prevent users with no relationship from viewing each others statuses stream

Tags: users

I have Statuses and user relationship module installed. I would like to prevent users who do not have a relationship from being able to view each others statuses stream.

It appears that by default, when a user visits any user profile, he/she is able to view the status update box and status stream of the other user irrespective of if they are "friends" or not.

I want to prevent this. I do not mind them viewing the status update box, but not the stream.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, can someone with a higher reputation add "Statuses" to the tag. It does not seem to previously exist.